# Why does Git keep ignoring subfolder

Tags: git, ignore

I have this .gitignore file:

```
# Ignore wordpress
/wordpress/
/wordpress/*

# Except the wp-content folder
!/wordpress/wp-content/
!/wordpress/wp-content/*
```

But when I change something in wp-content the changes aren't listed by git status, and if I do

```
git add wordpress/wp-content
```

I still get a warning .gitignore contains /wordpress/ and so doesn't add the changes. Why is this?

**Aditional**

I'm on OSx, running git 1.7.3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that you want to ignore the `wordpress` directory itself because there are some things in the `wordpress` directory that you do want to track. You only need to ignore *most* of the top-level paths in the `wordpress` directory.

This `.gitignore` should be sufficient.

```
# ignore most things in the wordpress directory
/wordpress/*

# ... except the wp-content directory
!/wordpress/wp-content/
```

Comment: Oooh, of course. I did not get the difference between ignoring a folder and ignoring the contents of the folder, but not the folder itself. This worked, thanks!